# Laravel 5.1 Redis - create cache for existing data

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-5.1, phpredis

I am looking for some way to create cache for the existing data I have in laravel db.  I have searched around the web. There are plenty of tips on how to enable caching for new data but none for existing.   Example would be a large number of products for sale that are in my inventory database.  A good example would be the controller function below.  How can I cache this query?  $hotel is the json response.

public function gethotels(Request $request)
     {

```
    $hotels = DB::table('hotel')->get();

    return $hotels;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using SADD command to add the query results.